# Angular Synchronous operations in API

Tags: c#, angular

I have a question in regard to running synchronous operations in an API design.   I understand fully running asynchronous in certain scenarios like this is the correct approach this is more a conceptual understanding.  If I have an Angular front end where the user can call an API endpoint with Subscribe which passes a list of CustomerId's.   In the API a synchronous ActionResult is called which then iterates through these customer id's and calls a synchronous database call that can take a good amount of time to complete for each call.

The question I have is does that actually lock up the service if another user takes an action in the same UI against the backend service will the service not respond until that other user action is complete?  I am just trying to wrap my head around that concept does the service lock up in that case and the UI would not be responsive.  Multitask programming of course is the way to handle this just conceptually.

Thanks for input.

Comment: another use is another instance of client. users are fully independent from each other, so there is a concurrency problem that may happen when 2 users click the same button simultaniously. you should solve you problem in your c# backend

Comment: Just to underscore @Andrei's point, and since you obviously care about your server performance, it's a travesty to write synchronous database access code in C#.

Comment: I understand it should be async I am asking about what exactly is happening on the server does the service lockup for all users based on the question.  @Aluan

Comment: When you perform synchronous io on your server, you block the executing thread. In asp.net, there is some inherent concurrency and parallelism because multiple different requests can be and often are served by different threads. It depends on the system that you're running it on. If you have only a few logical cores the impact of sync IO will be greater. Without knowing how much traffic you have for and how much data you manipulate Etc it's hard to say how severe the real world impact will be but it's just wasteful to use sync IO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are missing is:-

1. angular runs on client end it means that every user will have an instance running on his system and his local instance may fail and in a result that particular client's instance may fail.
2. If using asynchronous backend it also won't stop it may fail the process and respond accordingly(if all errors have been handled). In the worst-case scenario even if it fails server gets restarted as mostly it's monitored using process managers like pm2. which takes no time to restart it.

so basically nothing gets blocked until there is an issue on your server and server stops to respond.